# Python: How to sample from a priority queue?

Tags: python, priority-queue

As the title suggests, it seems in python the priority queue is not iterable nor can it be passed to `random.sample`. But I want to randomly select samples from it, what should I do?

Comment: You can consider using heapq instead. Then it will be the same as normal list. https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html

Comment: What implementation of a priority queue are you using?

Comment: @AChampion I'm using queue.PriorityQueue.

Comment: @stanleyli `queue.PriorityQueue` uses `heapq` underneath.

Comment: If you need thread synchronization, you cannot safely access the internals of a `queue.PriorityQueue`. If you _don't_ need thread synchronization, you shouldn't be using the `queue` module in the first place; just use `heapq` directly (or build your own trivial wrapper around it), and then you can just sample from the list.

Comment: Thx. I've use `heapq` to do the job

Answer (score 0):

The raw list for `queue.PriorityQueue` can be referenced through the `queue` attribute, so you can `random.sample()` with:

```
pq = queue.PriorityQueue()
...
random.sample(pq.queue, n)
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. The whole point of `queue.PriorityQueue` (and everything in the `queue` module) is that it's auto-synchronized: access to it is always thread-safe. But accessing `pq.queue` is _not_ thread-safe. So either this is adding a dangerous race condition to the code, or the OP shouldn't have been using the `queue` module in the first place.